# named entity as pointer to T in template parameter list

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, standards

In C++11 standard (clause 3.3.9/3) i found this code snippet:

```
template<class T, T* p, class U = T> class X { /∗ ... ∗/ };
```

Can anybody explain for me which possible (and usefull) code can contain in body of class X?
With usage of parameter `p` ofcourse.

Comment: IMHO the snippet is just there to demonstrate that template parameters can be dependent on a prior template parameter.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ, I know. But when i saw pointer as named template parameter i thought: "In which cases this can be usefull"? and could not find answer except like this: `constexpr T* ptr= nullptr;` and then use 'ptr' as parameter.

Comment: Yes, or any other reasonable and valid constant address (consider going down to the bare metal, e.g. extended bus interfaces, etc.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `foo` is a global object of type `T`, you can pass a pointer-to-`foo` to the `template class X`.

As an example, suppose `T` was an `ostream`.  I can create two logging types, which based on the type output to error or out.  Their `static` methods can even do it.